# Template function ignores members from inherited class

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I am trying to write a program that compares some Shapes by their area, Shape being the base class.
The program has 2 other classes that are derived from the Shape class.

This is how I defined them:

```
class Shape
{
protected:
    string color;
public:
    Shape();
    Shape(string);
    virtual double Perimeter();
    virtual void printMe();
    virtual double Area();
};

class Square:
    public Shape
{
    int x, y;
    double side;
public:
    Square();
    Square(string, int, int, double);
    double Perimeter();
    void printMe();
    double Area();
};

class Circle:
    public Shape
{
    int x, y, radius;
public:
    Circle();
    Circle(string, int, int, int);
    double Perimeter();
    void printMe();
    double Area();
};
```

In main, I created the following objects:

```
Shape f1, f2("green");
Circle c1, c2("green", 2, 2, 2);
Square p1, p2("blue", 0, 0, 5);

Shape* f3 = &c1;
Shape* f4 = &c2;
Shape* f5 = new Square("blue", 1, 0, 2);
Shape* f6 = &p2;
```

And I want to build a function that takes any Shape objects and return the one that has the maximum area.
I tried like this:

```
template <typename T>
T maxim(initializer_list<T> list) {
    T maxx;
    for (auto i : list)
    {
        if (i.Area() > maxx.Area())
            maxx = i;
    }
    return maxx;
}
```

In main, I tried to call the function:

```
maxim<Shape>({*f3, *f4, *f5, *f6}).printMe();
```

The program doesn't have any errors, only an empty string is displayed (due to the fact that `maxx` is a `Shape` that is initialized with an empty string).

The objects `f3`,`f4`,`f5` and `f6` are displayed right when I call the `printMe()` method, so I figured that when I call the `maxim` function, only the member `color` is assigned to the objects. There is no `x`,`y`,`side` or `radius` member assigned to them.

I think the problem is that the objects are just `Shapes` and they only have the `color` member.
Is there any way the objects in the list can be interpreted as Cricles and Squares so I can compare them using `Area()` method?

Comment: You have object slicing with `std::initializer_list<Shape>`. you need reference/pointer.

Comment: @Jarod42 could you please elaborate?

Comment: Read [what-is-object-slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use polymorphism here. Unfortunately polymorphism in C++ works well with pointers or references but not with plain objects because of [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) (thank to @Jarod42 for that reference).

And as references cannot be assigned to (you instead assign to the ref-ed object) you cannot use them in containers **nor in initializer lists**.

That means that you will have to use good old pointers in `maxim`:

```
template <typename T>
T* maxim(initializer_list<T*> list) {
    T* maxx = nullptr;
    for (auto i : list)
    {
        if (nullptr == maxx || i->Area() > maxx->Area())
            maxx = i;
    }
    return maxx;
}
```

From there on, you will be able to do:

```
maxim<Shape>({f3, f4, f5, f6})->printMe();
```